# Rotate Atlas Region Libgdx

Tags: java, image, rotation, libgdx, atlas

```
protected TextureAtlas atlas = Assets.manager.get(Constants.ATLAS_PATH, TextureAtlas.class);

AtlasRegion region = interfaceAtlas.findRegion("arrow");
```

I've load an image like this (http://marinedealerconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/right.png): an arrow that points right...

But I can't find a way to rotate it!
How can I? Because I want it goes down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot rotate region although you can rotate [Sprite](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) or [Image](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html)

```
    //sprite:
    public void rotate(float degrees)

    //image - remember to set origin to the center here!
    public void rotateBy(float amountInDegrees)
```

Instead of rotating the region itself you can "tell" SpriteBatch to draw it rotated:

```
    batch.draw(region, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation);
```

Comment: I've used the draw rotation!

It works!  :)
Thank you!

Comment: "rotation" parameter is rotating the image always from "left bottom". Can i rotate "region" from region's center point with "batch.draw"?  (Note: i don't want to use Sprite or Image it's too costy.)

Comment: I suppose that you need to specify proper `originX, originY` then (at the center of region not `0, 0`)